# Let $U$ and $V$ be any two open sets with $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $F\subset U\cup V$. Show that there is an integer $n$ with $F_n\subset U\cup V$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F_n$ be a sequence of compact and connected sets with $F_{n+1}\subset F_n$ and let $F$ be the intersection of $F_n$, $n=1,2,...$. Let $U$ and $V$ be any two open sets with $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $F\subset U\cup V$.

(a) Show that there is an integer $n$ with $F_n\subset U\cup V$.

(b) Show that $F$ is connected.

I try to use the Nested Set Property to prove, but i'm not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Where do $U$ and $V$ live ? Do you assume that the $F_n$ are subspaces of a topological space $X$ and $U,V$ too ?

Comment: Think about $K_{n} = F_{n} \setminus  \left ( U \cup V \right )$

Answer (score 0):

Answer on (a) under extra condition that the compact $F_n$ are closed in $F_1$.

We work in compact space $F_1$. The compact $F_{1}$ is covered by the family 
$\left(O_{k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}$ open in $F_1$, where $O_{0}:=F_1\cap(U\cup V)$
and $O_{k}:=F_{1}\backslash F_{k}$. There is a finite subcover and
$F_{1}\subset\cup_{k=0}^{n}O_{n}$ implies $F_{1}\subset O_0\cup F_{1}\backslash F_{n}$. Here $F_{n}\subset F_{1}$ hence $F_{n}\subset O_0\subset U\cup V$.